# Updating object in C# with data that came from JSInterop not re-rendering

Tags: blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I have a simple component let's say it list some customers that came from IndexedDB, I can retrieve the data perfectly fine, even see the object get the value if put some breakpoints, but the component is not re-rendering after it get the data update.

For simplicity Customers.razor :

```
@inject IJSRuntime js
@foreach(var item in Data)
{
    <h5>@item.Name</h5>
}
@code{
    protected List<CustomerModel> Data { get; set; }

    protected override  async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        Data = await js.InvokeAsync<List<CustomerModel>>("Database.get", "customers");
    }
}
```

Running Blazor on .NET Core 3.1, is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@inject IJSRuntime js

@* Verify that the data is not null and the list contains items, otherwise
   an exception is thrown *@ 
@if( Data != null && Data.Any())
{
    @foreach(var item in Data)
    {
        <h5>@item.Name</h5>
    }
}


@code{
    protected List<CustomerModel> Data { get; set; }

    protected override  async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Call only once 
        if( firstRender )
        {
             Data = await js.InvokeAsync<List<CustomerModel>>("Database.get", 
                                                             "customers");
             InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged();});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't need the InvokeAsync, directly invoking the Statehaschanged(); inside the validation of firstRender did the trick, thank you

Comment: It's a good practice to use the InvokeAsync as Blazor is evolving and not in the far future both flavors of Blazor may use multiple threads

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected override  async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
 {
     Data = await js.InvokeAsync<List<CustomerModel>>("Database.get", "customers");

     StateHasChanged();
 }
```

Should work but maybe `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` will be required.

Comment: StateHasChanged(); was the missing part, thank you but a quick note, has to validate is the firstRender == true because if not, got a infinite re-render